# Ruby library for Objective-C syntax highlighing

Tags: html, objective-c, ruby, syntax-highlighting

I have a blog built with Ruby, but I frequently blog about Objective-C topics.

I thus need a Ruby library that can take Objective-C source code strings and produce syntax-highlighted HTML output.

For Ruby source strings, I am happily using the syntax gem - http://syntax.rubyforge.org/ - but I can't find an Objective-C tokenizer for this library.

Is there an open source tokenizer available, or another library which can do this in Ruby?

If all else fails, all I've found is a PHP library (GeSHi) which claims to have Obj-C support, and I'll have to install PHP on my host, write a janky shell exec based invocation of it. I would love to avoid this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little digging on Google led me to [this gem, Highlight](http://simplabs.github.com/highlight/), which supports Objective-C. There are a few other Ruby gems [listed here](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/syntax_highlighting.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just use a command line tool to do this and the best possible solution is surely **[Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/)**, and if you're running on a Linux hosting you probably have Python installed already.

Just call it from the command line and store the output somewhere.

Comment: GitHub has even already done the work for you. Check out Albino: https://github.com/github/albino.